# Virginia non-stock corporate board elections

Tags: corporate-law, virginia

Can a non-stock corporation with one class of voting members establish two classes of Board Directors, and then tell members to vote for a certain number of nominees from each class?  Is that practice in compliance with:

> **13.1-846. Voting entitlement of members.**
>   C. Unless the articles of incorporation provide otherwise, in the election of directors every member, regardless of class, is entitled to one vote for as many persons as there are directors to be elected at that time and for whose election the member has a right to vote.

In other words, can a board write bylaws establishing a certain class of board directors, and then force the membership to vote for someone in that class?

Here is the section from the articles of incorporation:

> The directors of the corporation shall be elected by the members at the Annual Meeting, at which time the members shall elect the number of directors whose terms have expired. The initial Board of Directors shall serve until the first Annual Meeting to be held in 1994 when elections shall be held to fill all positions on the Board of Directors. Half of those elected to the Board of Directors at that time shall serve for half a term and half serve for a full term. Thereafter directors shall serve for two-year staggered terms.

Comment: As noted in the statute you quote, it depends on the articles of incorporation.  Though I suspect that they cannot *force* anyone to vote for anyone, regardless.  A qualified voter can always abstain.

Comment: Here is the section from the articles of incorporation:  The directors of the corporation shall be elected by the members at the Annual Meeting, at which time the members shall elect the number of directors whose terms have expired.  The initial Board of Directors shall serve until the first Annual Meeting to be held in 1994 when elections shall be held to fill all positions on the Board of Directors.  Half of those elected to the Board of Directors at that time shall serve for half a term and half serve for a full term.  Thereafter directors shall serve for two-year staggered terms.

Comment: Then can a board run an election that says to members "please pick three candidates from list A and one from list B" ?